# How do i iterate over an array of object in react.js and add the values of prices in the object as shown below

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```js
const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "buttermilk pancakes",
        category: "fullstack",
        price: 15.99,
        img: "./img/item-1.jpeg",
        desc: `I'm baby woke mlkshk wolf bitters live-edge blue bottle, hammock freegan copper mug whatever cold-pressed `,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "diner double",
        category: "backend",
        price: 13.99,
        img: "./img/item-2.jpeg",
        desc: `vaporware iPhone mumblecore selvage raw denim slow-carb leggings gochujang helvetica man braid jianbing. Marfa thundercats `,
    },
];

export default data;
```

Here i looped through the object using map but the returned result displays the iterated price sums.
I also used the JavaScript function reduce and that did not work either.

```
const Test = () => {
    let sum = 0;
    return (
        <div>
            {data.map((items) => {
                const values = items.price;
                sum = values + sum;
                console.log(Math.max(sum));
                const { id } = items;
                return (
                    <div key={id}>
                        <p>{sum}</p>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
};
```

How do I get the total value of the price using react?

Comment: Create a function which return the sum and call that function in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply achieve the calculation of total price using `forEach` instead of `map` (as map has its own use case like creating new array, and `forEach` is available for us just for this simple iteration like in your use case) with a one-liner like:

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'buttermilk pancakes',
    category: 'fullstack',
    price: 15.99,
    img: './img/item-1.jpeg',
    desc: `I'm baby woke mlkshk wolf bitters live-edge blue bottle, hammock freegan copper mug whatever cold-pressed `,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'diner double',
    category: 'backend',
    price: 13.99,
    img: './img/item-2.jpeg',
    desc: `vaporware iPhone mumblecore selvage raw denim slow-carb leggings gochujang helvetica man braid jianbing. Marfa thundercats `,
  }
];

var sum = 0;
data.forEach(subData => sum += subData.price);
console.log(sum) // return this `sum` value alone in your div tag below.

//return <div>{sum}</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `reduce` function to achieve this

```js
data.reduce((sum, p)=> sum+p.price, 0);
```

You can use it inside your component

```
const Test = ()=> {
    return <div>{data.reduce((sum, p)=> sum+p.price, 0);}</div>
 }
```

Comment: this is more efficient. follow this!

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this code, it may help your code

```
const Test = () => {
    let sum = 0;
    data.forEach((item) => {
     sum = sum + item.price;
    });

    return(
     <div> {sum} </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const Test = ()=> {
    var prices = data.map(({price})=> price).reduce((a, b)=> a+b, 0);
    return(
     <div>
         {prices}
     </div>
    )
 }
```

thank you everyone, I also tried this and it worked.